# ReferenceError: employeelist is not defined

Tags: html, angularjs

I am unable to solve my issue here please look into my code and provide a solution for it

[image: here is the error image]

here is the code of server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))

app.listen(3000);
console.log("server running on port 3000")
```

here is code of controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Hello World from controller");
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/employeelist'
    }).then(function (response) {
           > console.log("I got the data I requested");
            $scope.employeelist = response.data;
        });
    employee1 = {
        name: 'Sunil',
        designation: 'Software Developer',
        salary: '20000'
    };
    employee2 = {
        name: 'Vamshi',
        designation: 'Java Developer',
        salary: '30000'
    };

    employee3 = {
        name: 'Chethan',
        designation: 'Dot Net Developer',
        salary: '20000'
    };

    var employeeList = [employee1, employee2, employee3];

    $scope.employeelist = employeelist;
}]);
```

here is the code of html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <title>Employees List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <h1>Employees List</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Designation</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in employeelist">
                    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.designation}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
<script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/
angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

is the error is about the version of angular or have I done anything wrong in my code?

node server is working fine but when I open the localhost the above errors are displaying and also i am unable to view this line **console.log("I got the data I requested");**

Comment: you are assigning `$scope.employeelist = employeelist;` what is `employeelist` I see you define a `employeeList` as an array above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because **JavaScript is case sensitive**

Your local variable is called `employeeList` but you are trying to assign `employeelist` to `$scope.employeelist` and so `employeelist is not defined`.

Change this:

```
var employeeList = [employee1, employee2, employee3];
$scope.employeelist = employeelist;
```

To this:

```
var employeeList = [employee1, employee2, employee3];
$scope.employeelist = employeeList; // uppercase "L"
```

Comment: yes now its displaying data but there is one more error that i am unable to print this line console.log("I got the data I requested"); in the node server

Comment: @sunilBhatraju In that case you should mark as answer and create a new question asking how to solve the new problem you're experiencing.

Comment: i did now marked ur answer as answered @Matthew Cawley

Comment: can u do a favor and upvote my answer here in this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292763/possibly-unhandled-rejection-for-http-request

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive, you have `var employeeList` followed by `$scope.employeelist = employeelist;`  change the first to `var employeelist` and it should work